# How to open a component in ng-bootstrap modal using a specific injector?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-modal, ng-bootstrap

I'm starting use ng-bootstrap modal to open my components in popups. I have many components and each of them needs your own injector, because each one use a different instance of the same services. Is there any way to pass the component and the injector like in "ViewContainerRef":

```
let componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(myComponentFactory, 0, myInjector, []);
```

I need something like this:

```
NgbModal.open(MyComponet, myInjector);
```

Thanks.

---

Edited to add more details.

My services and objects that I need inject, are determined at run-time, something like this:

```
// Services
@Injectable()
export class MyService1 {
    constructor(
        @Inject('ServiceProvider') private _serviceProvider: any
    ) { }
}

@Injectable()
export class MyService2 {
    constructor(
        @Inject('ServiceProvider') private _serviceProvider: any
    ) { }
}

// Components
@Component({
   ...
})
export class CompA {
    constructor(
        @Inject('MyService') private _service: MyService1 | MyService2,
        @Inject('MyParentService') private _parentService: MyService1 | MyService2
    ) { }
}

@Component({
   ...
})
export class CompB {
    constructor(
        @Inject('MyService') private _service: MyService1 | MyService2,
        @Inject('MyParentService') private _parentService: MyService1 | MyService2
    ) { }
}
```

So, when the user requests an action, I need to provide the correct service (for the component) and the correct "ServiceProvider" (for the service). This is what occurs in the parent:

```
switch (action) {
    case 'one':
        providers = [
            {provide: 'MyService', useClass: MyService1},
            {provide: 'ServiceProvider', useValue: this._objectsA}
        ];
        break;
    case 'two':
        providers = [
            {provide: 'MyService', useClass: MyService2},
            {provide: 'ServiceProvider', useValue: this._objectsB}
        ];
        break;
}

providers = providers.concat([
    {provide: 'MyParentService', useValue: this._service}
]);

switch (context) {
    case 'add':
        component = compA;
        break;
    case 'edit':
        component = compB;
        break;
}

let resolvedProviders = ReflectiveInjector.resolve(providers),
    childInjector = ReflectiveInjector.fromResolvedProviders(resolvedProviders, this._injector);

// It was good if I'm able to resolve the component dynamically
let factory = this._componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(component);

// And finally open my popup
this._ngbModal.open(factory, childInjector);

// Like when we use the viewContainerRef
// let componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(factory, 0, childInjector, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't it work by default?

Say you have two components, each declaring the same service:

```ts
@Component({
  providers: [MyService]
})
export class CompA {
  constructor(private service: MyService) { }
}

@Component({
  providers: [MyService]
})
export class CompB {
  constructor(private service: MyService) { }
}
```

Then, when you instantiate these components via the modal service:

```ts
NgbModal.open(CompA);
NgbModal.open(CompB);
```

They each get a different instance of `MyService`, no?

Comment: Yes, you are right, but I only know what I need inject at run-time. I edited the post to add more details. Thanks for your answer.